# Started programs by shell can't write files! Why?

Tags: fopen, writefile

I wrote somethig like a Watchdog in C that whatch for some programs and, if those programs have saty off, it start those programs up.

Ok!

But I have one program that have to write a file, and when I play it works very well, but when my watchdog play it (by shell command), my program don't write the file.

I have the rights to write the file.

Could someone help me?

Thankz!

(in advance sorry for my poor english...)

Comment: You tagged this question `s` -- did you mean to tag it `shell` instead?

Comment: Can you create a [mcve]?

Comment: Sure Daniel! And sorry for the long time...

Comment: Sure Daniel! And sorry for the long time...

My main code:
`code`
errno_t erro;
FILE *LSW;

erro = fopen_s(&LSW, "file.txt", "w");

if(erro == 0) {
 fprint_s(LSW, "%s", "Test");
 fclose(LSW);
}
`code`

My Shell Command on a VB code:
`code`
Shell("programName.exe", AppWonStyle.NormalFocus)
`code`

Thank you!

Comment: Please edit your code into your question (where it can be formatted) rather than putting it into a comment, and please provide a *complete* example that reproduces the problem. Also, please update your tags: you probably want to tag this question VB if you're using it to launch the subprocess.